# Squid ignoring hosts file (using SquidMan on Mac)

Tags: mac-osx, squid, hosts

I installed [SquidMan 3.1](http://web.me.com/adg/squidman/) on my Mac, and it works fine. But I really need it to redirect some of the traffic using my hosts file, and it seems to be ignoring it no matter where I put it.

So far I've tried:

- Adding a `hosts_file /etc/hosts` directive on the configuration template via the SquidMan UI.
- Adding the same directive on the configuration file located at `/usr/local/squid/etc/squid.conf`
- Creating a copy of my hosts file in `/usr/local/squid/etc/` and updating the directives to match the new location.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The location on the hosts file on Mac OS X is /private/etc/hosts

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

Comment: Yes, `/etc/` is the same as `/private/etc/`

Comment: @luchomolina technically its not, /etc is just a symlink that has been hidden w/ `chflags hidden`